# Database Synchronization through API - Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, api, synchronization

What is the best way to sync data from a central server, to n local servers, working in both ways ?

Let's say we have 100 stores, and each store has it's own server, where a customer comes in, makes an operation, and types in it's name.

Now, we would store the client details in the local server, and then through an API, will make a call to the central server, to store the client in a central database.

From the central database, we would like to either :
a). Push this data to the rest of 99 stores, so that basically every one is synced.
b). Pull the new data from the 100 stores.

My question is, what's the best mechanism/pattern, to know exactly WHAT data the local stores misses from the central store, so that when we sync, if the central database has 600.000 customers, we should only get for example only 100 (because that's the difference).

Comment: The best way is to use the built-in replication functionality that many databases provide.

Comment: There is no out-of the box solution for that. You'll have to design an application that does that and write code. This question is too broad, it lacks focus. You can ask for a single technical problem or design issue, but not for "how do I design this application".